# tkinter fill=Y does not work with Button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

On macOS Sierra, with py2.7.13 and py3.6,

I expected the following code to look like:
[image]

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text="A").pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.Y)
tk.Button(root, text="B").pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
tk.Button(root, text="C").pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.NONE, anchor = tk.NE)
tk.Button(root, text="D").pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.NO, fill=tk.Y)
tk.Button(root, text="E").pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=tk.NO, fill=tk.BOTH)
tk.Button(root, text="F").pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.NO, fill=tk.NONE)
tk.Button(root, text="G").pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.Y)
tk.Button(root, text="H").pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=tk.NO, fill=tk.BOTH)
tk.Button(root, text="I").pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.NO)
tk.Button(root, text="J").pack(anchor=tk.SE)
root.mainloop()
```

But got 
[image]

So those Buttons with fill=Y didn't expand and fill vertically.

However, Labels behave as expected:
[image]

with the code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="A", bg='green').pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.Y)
tk.Label(root, text="B", bg='red').pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
tk.Label(root, text="C", bg='blue').pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.NONE, anchor=tk.NE)
tk.Label(root, text="D", bg='yellow').pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.NO, fill=tk.Y)
tk.Label(root, text="E", bg='purple').pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=tk.NO, fill=tk.BOTH)
tk.Label(root, text="F", bg='pink').pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=tk.NO, fill=tk.NONE)
tk.Label(root, text="G", bg='green').pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.Y)
tk.Label(root, text="H", bg='red').pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=tk.NO, fill=tk.BOTH)
tk.Label(root, text="I", bg='blue').pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.NO)
tk.Label(root, text="J", bg='yellow').pack(anchor=tk.SE)
root.mainloop()
```

What am I missing here? Is it by design that Buttons behave differently from Labels?